# 3D Touch Peek - Background Blur Color

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, 3dtouch, peek

When 3D Touch Peek is invoked, the background blur that happens, I notice it varies.

For example, it's a LIGHT blur in iMessage, but DARK blur in FaceTime App.

*(Although below image might not be the best example to show the contrast, you can notice it better through out iOS 10)*

[image]

Is this done automatically from the context brightness? Background View brightness? Peek context brightness? Or do we have any control over this?

---

```
extension ChatTableViewController: UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate {
    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location) else { return nil }

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: ChatDetailViewController.identifier)
        guard let chatDetailViewController = viewController as? ChatDetailViewController else { return nil }

        chatDetailViewController.chatItem = chatItem(at: indexPath)
        let cellRect = tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
        previewingContext.sourceRect = previewingContext.sourceView.convert(cellRect, from: tableView)
        chatDetailViewController.isReplyButtonHidden = true

        return chatDetailViewController
    }

    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commit viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {
        if let chatDetailViewController = viewControllerToCommit as? ChatDetailViewController {
            chatDetailViewController.isReplyButtonHidden = false
        }
        show(viewControllerToCommit, sender: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was messing around with some properties of `UIViewController` trying to figure out how to do this, and it turns out that changing `preferredStatusBarStyle` will change the blur color.

To change the peek blur style from light to dark, you can change `preferredStatusBarStyle` from `.default` to `.lightContent`

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController{
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle{
        return .lightContent
    }
}
```

This also works with a hidden status bar

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController{
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool{
        return true
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle{
        return .lightContent
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You are AMAZING!!